# Using Active Merchant on Ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activemerchant, ruby-1.8.7

I am using Site5 to host my site, and which limits me to use ruby 1.8.7.  However, I can't install the Active Merchant gem because it has Money as a dependancy - which requires Ruby 1.9.2!  Is there any way to work around this?  Perhaps declaring a older version of ACtive Merchant or Money?  Will it still be functional if this is done?

This is the error I am getting:

```
Installing money (5.1.1) 
Gem::InstallError: money requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2.
An error occurred while installing money (5.1.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install money -v '5.1.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use bundler to figure out which version you can use.

Otherwise, use `git` or github to blame the dependency. For example, you can see that the [1.9.2 dependency](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money/commit/81837dbaf690a46225ec021c2bf624f97e1bf1d7) was added in version 5, so anything older should be fine. You'll have to dig out which version of ActiveMerchant can the use `money` 4.x.

Comment: I ended up just specifying the version in the gemfile, and figuring out which one was compatible through trial and error.  Turns out its 1.21.0 if anyone is curious... perhaps you could post the code that you could use to do that?